# How to check that I went through all data within one epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I check that `sess.run` got through all data within one epoch without specifing `num_epochs` in `slice_input_producer`?

I thought that using `while not coord.should_stop()` (see code below) should stop once it went through all data, but it never stops. It just iterates over and over.

Is the only solution to set `num_epochs=1` in `slice_input_producer` and than catch it in `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` and thus I'll know that that it went through all data?

```
batch_size = 3
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_filenames, label_filenames], 
                                                num_epochs=None,
                                                shuffle=True)
image_batch, label_batch = generate_batch(input_queue, batch_size) 

with tf.Session(...) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())            
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            images,labels = sess.run([train_image_batch, train_label_batch])
            pltShow(images, labels)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('OutOfRangeError')
    finally:
        print("requesting threads to stop.")
        coord.request_stop()
```

**UPDATE1**

I tried setting `num_epochs=1` in `slice_input_producer` and then doing this, but it didn't help. It stops after first epoch

```
epoch = 0
while epoch < 10:
    try:             
        while not coord.should_stop():
            images,labels = sess.run([train_image_batch, train_label_batch])
            pltShow(images, labels)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('OutOfRangeError')
    finally:
        print("requesting threads to stop.")

    epoch += 1
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `num_epochs`?

Comment: I just want to know when each epoch ends. If I'll use `num_epochs` there is no way to know that. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh ok, now I see what you are after.

Comment: What about counting the number of processed samples? I supposed you considered that option, why wouldn't it work for you?

Comment: But I don't know how many samples I have in the first place. So, how would I know if one epoch ended?

Comment: In your example, isn't the number of samples given by `len(image_filenames)`?

Comment: `image_filenames` along with `slice_input_producer` are actually inside the `generate_batch` function. I probably could make `generate_batch` to return the number of examples.